# How to display all folders under a folder when user type path in textbox?

Tags: wpf, directory

I have a wpf-mvvm application. I have one textbox and one button (similar to FileUpload control). How can I display all folders under a given folder ..when user type it.

I mean similar to..when windows display all folders under c drive..when we type c:\ in start->RUN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad question so I will give you an outline of a possible solution.

Each time the text in the `TextBox` changes you would check whether that is a real folder on disk using [`Directory.Exists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx). If it does exist you would call [`Directory.GetDirectories()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) to get a list of all the subfolders. Add those subfolders to an `ObservableCollection<string>` object and use an `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` of some kind to bind to the collection of subfolders.

How do you know when the text of the `TextBox` changes as the user types? There are two ways. First way is to bind to a property and use `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` in the binding so that the property is set as the user types. A second way would be to handle the `TextBox`'s `TextChanged` event.

Comment: Or is Anish asking about how to do a "typeahead" under the text box? It's not clear.

Comment: I don't know exactly what he is asking.

Comment: Hi Brian...I was looking for same what you have given. Let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: Only concern is i cannt display as listbox...it should be like...A textbox..and when i type c:\ in that....all files or folders under c:\ should display as we can see in Windows-> start->RUN. I mean something like a textbox...and under this textbox...a "swoosh" listbox

Answer (score 1):

Control-wise, you might be looking for something like `AutoCompleteBox` or related from the WPF toolkit?
see : http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535 for wpf tookit info,
see : http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/wpfautocompletebox/ for a good blog post about how to use it.